# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'equals'

Tags: python, string, string-comparison, attributeerror

I keep getting this error and was wondering what was triggering it. This is my function definition:

```
def spectMixGen(M, samp_size, source_pdf = "uniform", pdf_pars = 1,
    pure_pixels = 'no', max_purity = np.ones((1, p)), 
    no_outliers = 0, violation_extremes = [1, 1.2],
    am_modulation = [1, 1], sig_variability = [1, 1],              
    snr = 40, noise_shape = 'uniform',
    noise_pars = [0, 1, 1])
```

and this is my function call:

```
spectMixGen(M, N, source_pdf = 'Diri_id', pdf_pars = SHAPE_PARAMETER, 
    max_purity = MAX_PURIRY*np.ones((1,p)), no_outliers = OUTLIERS, 
    violation_extremes = [1,1.2], snr = SNR, noise_shape = 'uniform')
```

The error points to this part of my code:

```
if (source_pdf == "Diri_mix"):
    no_modes, cols = pdf_pars.shape
    if cols is not (p+1):
        raise ValueError("Wrong pdf parameters")
    elif (np.sum(pdf_pars[:,1] != 1)) or (np.sum(pdf_pars[:,1] < 0) > 0):
        raise ValueError("Wrong pdf parameters -> mixing weights  do not define a probability")
```

with the message:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'equals'
```

Can anyone explain this error? I though that the function call sets the variable source_pdf equal to a string. Is this not the case?

Thanks

Comment: It's probably helpful to include the function body, and not just the signature.

Comment: Can you check what value and type the `source_pdf` variable actually has?

Comment: @DanielLenz source_pdf is defined in the function call. I called it as source_pdf = 'Diri_id'. I assumed this is a string?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga went back to add the rest of the code from where the error stems

Comment: There's still a code missing, do you do anything to the source_pdf variable? `'Diri_id' == "Diri_mix"` works perfectly fine and returns False.

Comment: Please make sure to always include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will also often help you answer the questions yourself.